# If cell has 2 words, extract only 1st word and if cell has 3 words, extract 2 first words - PANDAS/REGEX

Tags: python, regex, pandas

In my DataFrame, I have column named 'teams'. It includes the city and team name. I'd want to extract the city into another column. Here is the dataframe:
[DataFrame sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Bbx.png)

```
nba_df['team'].head(11)
    team
0   Toronto Raptors
1   Boston Celtics
2   Philadelphia 76ers
3   Cleveland Cavaliers
4   Indiana Pacers
5   Miami Heat
6   Milwaukee Bucks
7   Washington Wizards
8   Detroit Pistons
9   Charlotte Hornets
10  New York Knicks
```

I could easily extract the column using regex:

```
nba_df['cities'] = nba_df.team.str.extract('(^[\w*]+)', expand=True)
nba_df[['team', 'cities']].head(11)


    team                cities
0   Toronto Raptors     Toronto
1   Boston Celtics      Boston
2   Philadelphia 76ers  Philadelphia
3   Cleveland Cavaliers Cleveland
4   Indiana Pacers      Indiana
5   Miami Heat          Miami
6   Milwaukee Bucks     Milwaukee
7   Washington Wizards  Washington
8   Detroit Pistons     Detroit
9   Charlotte Hornets   Charlotte
10  New York Knicks     New
```

However, in the column 'names', for New York Knicks, it gives me only the value of: "New" and I'd like to get "New York":

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIsVH.png)

So, how should I do, if the cell has 2words, how can I extract only one word from the beginning and if the cell has 3words, how can I extract 2words from it using regex?

Comment: This may work **r'(?:(?!\s\w+$).)+'** This matches everything up to a space and final word.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.  Load a short DF from a dict; include that in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your scenario, where you have just 2 or 3 word strings, you can use

```
^(\S+(?:\s+\S+(?=\s+\S+))?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WGtRun/3).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\S+(?:\s+\S+(?=\s+\S+))?)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
  - `(?:\s+\S+(?=\s+\S+))?` - an optional sequence of

    - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
    - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespaces
    - `(?=\s+\S+)` - that is immediately followed with 1+ whitespaces and 1+ non-whitespaces.

Here are some other regex options:

- **All words but the last**: `^(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*)\s+\S+$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/WGtRun/4)) / `^(.*\S)\s+\S+$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/WGtRun/6/)) / `^(.*?)\s+\S+$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/WGtRun/5))
- **Get the first word in two-word string and two first words in a three word string, and no match in other strings**: `^(\S+(?=\s+\S+$)|\S+\s+\S+(?=\s+\S+$))` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/WGtRun/7))

Answer (score -1):

Don't struggle with regex for this, unless you find it *very* readable.  Instead, starting with the string `team_name` ... split, slice, and join:

```
team_words = team_name.split()
team_city = team_words[:-1]
city = ' '.join(team_city)
```

In one line:

```
city = ' '.join(team_name.split()[:-1])
```

Can you slip that readily into your DF broadcast?

Comment: Hey there! This is a nice solution as well! Thanks :)